# Redirect_uri with port number

Tags: autodesk-forge

My app uses 3-legged authentication and works on my machine. I have now set up a server and can reach the app by navigating to http://myservername:4000 .

However the settings on the forge portal don't let me enter the callback URL that I need: http://myservername:4000/api/forge/callback/oauth and the app gives an error at redirect.

It seems ports are only allowed for localhost, and that otherwise a domain must be provided, which I don't have at this stage.
Is that correct and are there workarounds to make it work without a domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried setting the callback URL for one of my Forge apps to:

- https://foobar.com:3000/auth/callback
- http://foobar.com:3000/auth/callback
- http://foobar:3000/auth/callback

And those all seem to work fine. What error message are you getting exactly? Is there perhaps some "bad character" in the URL you're trying to enter?

Comment: My servername was http://gosdev01:4000/api/forge/callback/oauth . It doesn't allow numbers apparently, as http://gosdev:4000/api/forge/callback/oauth works